# 'source-highlight' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: python, html, asciidoc

I was reading about asciidoc. I made an example in python but every time I try to display a code blog in html I end up getting an exception `'source-highlight' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`

**Python code**

```
from asciidocapi import AsciiDocAPI
asciidoc = AsciiDocAPI()
asciidoc.execute('mydoc.txt')
```

***mydoc.txt*** file:

```
== Example
.Optional Title
[source,python]
----
# *Source* block
# Use: highlight code listings
# (require `source-highlight` or `pygmentize`)
python('Hello world')
----
```

`source-highlight` in `asciidoc.config` file is not recognise as a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `source-highlighter=source-highlight` to `source-highlighter=pygments` in your `asciidoc.config`.

You have to have `pygments` installed (`pip install Pygments`).

I've tested on Ubuntu and the error message prior to changing the above setting was `/bin/sh: 1: source-highlight: not found`.